# gnome-control-center install error

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

When I  install gnome-control-center like that `sudo apt install gnome-control-center` Ubuntu gives this errors

```
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-control-center.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.4.0-42' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgupnp-1.2-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pymacaroons' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mobile-broadband-provider-info' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libzip5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-online-accounts' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcolord-gtk1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcolorhug2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-tz' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'colord-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgsound0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'icc-profiles-free' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-renderer-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-db-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjs-sphinxdoc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-core-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-control-center-faces' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjs-openlayers' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-protobuf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libieee1284-3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-rfc3339' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-macaroonbakery' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgupnp-av-1.0-2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libonig5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgssdp-1.2-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjs-underscore' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-server-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that doing `apt remove gnome-control-center` and `apt install gnome-control-center` fixes this.

However when launching from terminal a Gtk message "Failed to load module 'pantheon-filename-module'" appears, so perhaps indicating an incomplete or incorrect clean-up.